# It is possible to make public (and get the iframe code) a Google SpreadSheet using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm searching in Google Apps Scripts a way to make public a sheet of a a Google SpreadSheet.

I need that to insert the  code in a Google Site. I've found the way (under Sites Services - Google Apps Scripts) to modify the html code but i need to found the way to make public a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is no way to insert a spreadsheet view as a UI control inside a GAS Web App. There are the following workarounds

1. Simulate the view using standard [tab](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_decoratedtabpanel) and grid controls ([flex table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_flextable) or [chart table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tablechartbuilder));
2. Simulate the view using standard means of HTM;
3. Insert a [spreadsheet widget](http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=90569&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=l2uoml0dceht) to a site page.